# Is there a git diff option to tell me the relative names of all files that have changed in a diff?

Tags: git

I often find myself wanting to open all the files that were changed in a certain commit. My current solution is this, in an alias:

```
$EDITOR $(git diff --name-only --relative <commit names>)
```

Which works pretty well, but when I am in a subdirectory, then it doesn't open any files that were changed outside of that directory, because `git diff --name-only --relative` only outputs files changed in the current directory, not the whole repo. Is there a flag I can pass to `git diff` to make it include all changed files in the repo, even with `--relative`?

Comment: As a bonus, a way to not list the binary files would be handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git's own [aliases](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) allow you to specify shell commands by defining the alias with a leading exclamation point. These shell-command aliases always execute from the repository root, so you can use them in conjunction with the command you're already using by defining an alias in your `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    review-diff = "!edit() { $EDITOR $(git diff --name-only --relative \"$@\"); }; edit"
```

Then you can run `git review-diff` from anywhere in the repository.

(Note: I'm not sure when the version difference is, but newer versions of Git seem to allow you to skip the function wrapper in the alias, making for a simpler setup:)

```
[alias]
    review-diff = "!$EDITOR $(git diff --name-only --relative \"$@\")"
```

Comment: This seems to be pretty close, I have "diff-file-list = `!s $(git diff --name-only --relative \"$@\")"` as an alias (s is a bash function that launches my editor) and if I do `git diff-file-list HEAD^ HEAD` it opens the files just fine, but it also opens a new file named HEAD and one named HEAD^. This somewhat does the trick, as I only ever really want to open the files from the most recent commit, the staged changes, or the unstaged changed, and I can do an alias for each, but a more general solution would be nice.

Comment: Have you tried the longer version with the function (the first one in the answer)? That one should avoid the problem with the parameters being appended on the end.